# Data encapsulation, Instance variable cannot be accessed

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm having some trouble understanding what classes can read what variables in other classes. I've read to many different things online and cant seem to find anything solid in here. I've literally wasted the past two days trying to get my program to work but no classes can read any other classes variables. Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.

This is my ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    @public
    NSString *nameOfLabel;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstLabel;
- (IBAction)Switch:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)changeLabel:(UIButton *)sender;
-(NSString *) nameOfLabel;
@end
```

nameOfLabel is a public variable and should be able to be accessed by an outside class, right?

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NewView.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)Switch:(id)sender {
    NewView * new = [[NewView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController: new animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (IBAction)changeLabel:(UIButton *)sender  {
    nameOfLabel = @"Test Name";
    _firstLabel.text = nameOfLabel;
}
-(NSString *) nameOfLabel   {
    return nameOfLabel;
}
@end
```

changeLabel button changes *firstLabel.text to "Test name".

second class is NewView.h:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

    @interface NewView : UIViewController
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *secondLabel;
    - (IBAction)changeSecondLabel:(UIButton *)sender;
    @end
```

and NewView.m:

```
#import "NewView.h"

@interface NewView ()
@end

@implementation NewView
{
    ViewController *view;
}
- (IBAction)changeSecondLabel:(UIButton *)sender {
    view = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    _secondLabel.text = view.nameOfLabel;
}
@end
```

changeSecondLabel should change secondLabel.text to nameOfLabel which is 'Test name', however, the label actually disappears which makes me think that nameOfLabel cannot be reached. Ive played around with nameOfLabel, making it a @property and then synthesising it, as well as trying putting it in { NSString *nameOfLabel; } under @implementation but I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This line: `view = [[ViewController alloc] init];` creates a **new** ViewController which doesn't know anything about what you may have done to some other ViewController.  In your case, it specifically doesn't know that `changeLabel:` was called on another ViewController before this new one ever existed.

Comment: Okay well I removed that line and it still doesn't work. Even if I was to go to the next view and not changeLabel on the first view, the label would still disappear.

Comment: It certainly wouldn't work unless you made `view` point to a valid object (that is, the one that had the label you want).  If all you did was remove that one line, you've gone from using a new object to using none at all.

Comment: How would I go about making view point to the label fro the first ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

First of all please read about coding standards, it's not a good practice to:

1. Name variables like "new"
2. Name methods like "Switch"
3. Name UIViewController like "view" or "NewView"

Regarding logic:
This is all messed up here. What you actually do is you create viewController with nameOfLabel which is empty and is only changed on button press. I assume you press that button so it's changed. Then on switch action you create another viewController and present it. Then from inside that new viewController you create another new viewController which has empty nameOfLabel, get this empty value and put it inside secondLabel.

There are couple of ways you can do to change secondLabel:

1. Move nameOfLabel to model and read it from there when you want to change secondLabel,
2. Because your new viewController is child of viewController that keeps nameOfLabel you can access it by calling [[self presentingViewController] nameOfLabel] but make it property first,
3. Pass nameOfLabel through designated initializer.

Answer (score 0):

When the second view controller (NewView) is presented, it has no reference to the first view controller (ViewController) and it's data.

Here are a couple of suggestions.

- In modern Objective-C I'd recommend using properties instead of exposing a variable.
- Look over the naming in general. "ViewController" is not a good name for example.
- If the property is part of an internal state of the class, declare it in a class extension.
- Before you present the second view controller, set a reference to the string from the first view controller.

Part of ViewController.m:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *nameOfLabel;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)Switch:(id)sender {
    NewView *new = [[NewView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    new.secondLabel.text = self.nameOfLabel;
    [self presentViewController: new animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to do in the last bullet point, I've only just started Obj-C. I used the rest of the code you gave but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want a simple demonstration of access of a public ivar, the syntax is:

```
view->nameOfLabel;
    ^^
```

not dot-syntax:

```
view.nameOfLabel;
```

(dot-syntax just goes through accessor methods).

I've only seen a handful of warranted edge cases over the years; there's rarely, rarely ever a good reason to make an ivar public (also, protected is also rarely a *good* choice).